# How to automatically scroll horizontal to the middle inside a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I want to automatically scroll to the middle in the horizontal dimension, such that the red line (which is placed right in the middle of the svg) is in the middle.

Which values do I have to choose for `scrollLeft`?

```js
var div = $('.container');
div.animate({
  scrollLeft: div.width() / 2 + div.offset().left
});
```

```css
.container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: scroll;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class=container>
  <svg width="1000" height="400">
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
    <circle cx="200" cy="200" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
    <circle cx="600" cy="200" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
    <circle cx="40" cy="320" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
    <circle cx="960" cy="320" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />

    <line x1="499" y1="0" x2="499" y2="400" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:2" />

  </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be setting the `scrollLeft` property like below:

```
div.find('svg').width() / 2 - div.width() / 2
```

See demo below:

```js
var div = $('.container');
div.animate({
  scrollLeft: div.find('svg').width() / 2 - div.width() / 2
});
```

```css
.container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: scroll;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class=container>
  <svg width="1000" height="400">
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
    <circle cx="200" cy="200" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
    <circle cx="600" cy="200" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
    <circle cx="40" cy="320" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
    <circle cx="960" cy="320" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />

    <line x1="499" y1="0" x2="499" y2="400" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:2" />

  </svg>
</div>
```